# How to find all colorspaces used in a pdf?

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm trying to find all the colors and colorspaces used in a pdf using iText7.
I tried first exporting all the images in the pdf using an IEventListener.
For the events of type RENDER_IMAGE, I tried the GetGraphicsState().GetFillColor().GetColorSpace() to get the colorspace used.
I then catched the RENDER_TEXT and the RENDER_PATH to inspect the other objects of the PDF using the same methods.

However I don't really find what I'm looking for, I was expecting same pantone colors but they don't seems to register as such.

Here is my code for the event listener

```
public class ColorsListener : IEventListener
{
    public HashSet<iText.Kernel.Colors.Color> Colors = new HashSet<iText.Kernel.Colors.Color>();

    int idx = 0;
    public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case EventType.RENDER_TEXT:
                var tri = (TextRenderInfo)data;
                Colors.Add(tri.GetFillColor());
                Colors.Add(tri.GetStrokeColor());
                break;
            case EventType.RENDER_IMAGE:
                var iri = (ImageRenderInfo)data;
                Colors.Add(iri.GetGraphicsState().GetFillColor());
                Colors.Add(iri.GetGraphicsState().GetStrokeColor());
                break;
            case EventType.RENDER_PATH:
                var pri = (PathRenderInfo)data;
                Colors.Add(pri.GetFillColor());
                Colors.Add(pri.GetStrokeColor());
                break;
            case EventType.BEGIN_TEXT:
            case EventType.CLIP_PATH_CHANGED:
            case EventType.END_TEXT:
            default:
                if (data != null)
                {
                    var ri = (AbstractRenderInfo)data;
                    Colors.Add(ri.GetGraphicsState().GetFillColor());
                    Colors.Add(ri.GetGraphicsState().GetStrokeColor());
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it ? Will I find all the colors used in the pdf this way ? How to get the pantone values ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the related so question, if I understand correctly, I need to scan the content stream of the pdf to find all the colorspaces actually used in all the resources and objects of the pdf. Is using a PdfCanvasProcessor and an IEventListener the way to do it in iText7 ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, `PdfCanvasProcessor` is the right way to go

Comment: are you able to proceed so far with the `PdfCanvasProcessor` hint? You could modify your code in the question later on with `PdfCanvasProcessor` if you still have troubles and need help

Comment: Actually I found a way to avoid to code this feature. I had an old library that would do it that did not work with .Net Core, but I found a way to call it anyway. So I don't need it to do it myself anymore. Cheers